# Micro-services registration and discovery over AMQP

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices, distributed-computing, amqp, service-discovery

I'd like to maintain micro-services (several different types) topology over AMQP (RabbitMQ) with central registry for maintaining uptime and configuration:

- All micro-services connect to AMQP and publish its presence
- A master service wants to discover all worker services of a certain type
- A restarted worker service would read its last configuration from a central repository

Products like etcd and ZooKeeper are working over HTTP and not over AMQP.

Is there a standard way to do it over AMQP?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the RabbitMQ here is that what you need is special kind of persistence - but that's not present in the RabbitMQ.

Specifically, you may consider using "state of world" feature (missing in RabbitMQ). This basically means that the broker remembers the last message for a given key (or other combination). That could be used for implementation of the discovery service.

BUT - I still recommend to use e.g. ZooKeeper, since it provides also tools for detection of the abrupt micro-service disconnection; a feature that requires active "server side" functionality.